# How to use Axios in vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I would like to know how to use Axios in vueRouter in beforeEach()

i did like that :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    axios.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/me', {
    headers: {
        'x-access-token': $cookies.get('user_session') //the token is a variable which holds the token
    }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status == "200") {
            console.log('tet3');
        }
    }, response => {
        this.$cookies.remove("user_session");
        this.$router.push('/')
        //window.location.href = "/";
        console.log('erreur', response)
    })


if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

    if (!$cookies.get('user_session')) {
        next({
            path: '/login',
            params: {nextUrl: to.fullPath}
        })
    } else {
        let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.is_admin)) {
            if (user.is_admin == 1) {
                next()
            }
            else {
                next({name: 'userboard'})
            }
        }
        else {
            next()
        }
    }
} else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.guest)) {
    if ($cookies.get('user_session') == null) {
        next()
    }
    else {
        next({name: 'userboard'})
    }
} else {
    next()
}
})
```

and the result is an error :

*axios is not defined*

I can't use 'this', beceause 'this' is VueRouter

Do you know how to do ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you import `axios`?

Comment: [OT] An async call in routes doesn't seem like a good idea. You should handle this before or after you handle the route, so the user is not placed in a _limbo_ while the call is resolved. You can give the user a better experience if you handle it using global state.

Comment: I had imported Axios yes.

Ok thank you,
So where i need to test if the token is correct ?
I would like to handle this each time the router change (or maybe each time the user insert a cookie or change it)

So for the moment the token is checked on a specific component (mounted) and on the post http request.

Comment: All you should have to do is import axios and make sure you call next() in both a then() and a catch() for any promise based functionality in the router.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
})

...

http.get('me', {
    headers: {
        'x-access-token': $cookies.get('user_session') //the token is a variable which holds the token
    }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status == "200") {
            console.log('tet3');
        }
    }, response => {
        this.$cookies.remove("user_session");
        this.$router.push('/')
        //window.location.href = "/";
        console.log('erreur', response)
    })
```

...